# 1x10 drivetrain against 1x11 drivetrain on mountain bike

Tags: gears

What are the advantages/disadvantages apart from the obvious loss of one gear in the middle somewhere if both drivetrains start and end on the same size cogs

Comment: That's pretty much it. You get an extra gear ratio and closer spacing of ratios with 11 speed. 10 speed weighs 1 sprocket less I guess, chains and cassettes cheaper too.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus that's an answer not a comment.

Comment: 1×10 configurations are not officially supported by either of major vendors, AFAIK. Shimano started to offer wide 11-42 ten-speed cassettes only last year, while SRAM apparently focuses on 1×12. It does not mean that 1×10 will not work (it works for me and many others) nor that there is aftermarket support for it from smaller vendors. But there would certainly be more mix-and-match, experimentation and tinkering needed.

Answer (score 2):

You get an extra gear ratio and closer spacing of ratios with 11 speeds. 10 speeds drivetrains weigh 1 sprocket less I guess, and 10 speeds chains and cassettes are cheaper too.

Comment: I realized you edit a lot of stuff for language - grammatics,  Apparatus, I think your answer could use a little bit of that medicine ;)

Comment: Feel free to edit if you like :-)

Comment: It is often unfair to compare components weight and price unless a vendor offers exactly the same "brand" part with both configurations (10 and 11 speed). I mean, comparing 11 speed SLX and 10 speed SLX might make sense, but 11 speed SLX and 10 speed Deore are in different "weight classes" (literally). There is no 11 speed Deore setups, and a 10 speed SLX would be considered "outdated", which even makes new-apples to old-apples comparison. Comparing offers from different vendors is even trickier to make it fair.

Answer (score 2):

1×11 has extra gearing range, that's good. But you have to know, a 11 speed chain is thinner than 10 speed, so you should pay more attention to gear tuning. Spare parts for 1×11 are less common and more expensive. I don't know exactly, but I suspect that 11 speed transmission will be less reliable. 
In my bike store working experience, a SRAM GX group offers a rear derailleur that has a stronger spring; your chain will stay on the sprocket in most situations, but shifting would require more force.

Comment: >SRAM GX group will be more hard and destructible choose.  — So is it good thing or bad thing? I could not figure it out from your statement.

Comment: Im sorry about autocorrect, i ment 'hard and undestructble', 'hard' means the rear derailleur has more strong spring, and your chain will stay on the sprocket in most situations, but shifter has more hard gearshifts. 1x11 Gx will be nice choice if you ride xs with really bad terrain or am/enduro styles.